# Difference of derivative and slope of secant line

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, slope, secant

Let $f \colon [x_0,x_1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be smooth and $|f^{\prime \prime}(x)|\leq L$ for some $L \in \mathbb{R}^+$. I want to have an estimation of the form

$$
\left| f^\prime(x) - \frac{f(x_1)-f(x_0)}{x_1-x_0} \right| \leq K(x_0,x_1,L) \,.
$$

Any idea for a suitable $K$? Or do I need more assumptions for that?

Comment: Can you give more details? an initial idea that comes to mind is a linear growth bound. i.e. $K=L(1+|x_0|+|x_1|)$ which may not be a good bound for your purposes, need more information.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f: [x_0, x_1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be smooth, and $|f^{\prime \prime}(x)|\leq L$ for some $L \in \mathbb{R}^+$. We want to estimate the difference:

$\bigg| f^\prime(x) - \frac{f(x_1)-f(x_0)}{x_1-x_0} \bigg|$.

First, let's apply the mean value theorem to f on the interval $[x_0, x_1]$. There exists a point $c_1 \in (x_0, x_1)$ such that:

$f^\prime(c_1) = \frac{f(x_1) - f(x_0)}{x_1 - x_0}$.

Now, let's apply the mean value theorem to $f'$ on the interval $[x, c_1]$, where $x \in [x_0, x_1]$. There exists a point $c_2 \in (x, c_1)$ such that:

$f^{\prime\prime}(c_2) = \frac{f^\prime(c_1) - f^\prime(x)}{c_1 - x}$.

Since $|f^{\prime\prime}(x)| \leq L$, we have:

$\bigg|\frac{f^\prime(c_1) - f^\prime(x)}{c_1 - x}\bigg| = |f^{\prime\prime}(c_2)| \leq L$.

Multiplying both sides by $|c_1 - x|$, we get:

$|f^\prime(c_1) - f^\prime(x)| \leq L|c_1 - x|$.

Substituting the expression for $f^\prime(c_1)$, we have:

$\bigg| \frac{f(x_1)-f(x_0)}{x_1-x_0} - f^\prime(x) \bigg| \leq L|c_1 - x|$.

In this case, the estimation for the difference is:

$\bigg| f^\prime(x) - \frac{f(x_1)-f(x_0)}{x_1-x_0} \bigg| \leq L(x_1-x_0)$.

You might have to check for some special cases (e.g. $c_1=x_0$).
Does that make sense, I'm fairly new to Math.